# to get xpath in python selenium for ID and class together

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

[image]In python selenium, how to create xpath for below code which needs only id and class:

```
<button type="button" id="ext-gen756" class=" x-btn-text">Save</button>
```

And I also need to select Global ID from below drop-down without clicking it.

```
<div class="x-combo-list-item">Global ID</div>
```

My below solution is not working-

```
 //div[@class='x-combo-list-item']/div[contains(.,'Global ID')]
```

I do not want to mention `droplist` sequence number like-

```
//div[@class='x-combo-list-item']/div[1]
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to club `id` and `class` together in your `xpath` try like this-

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//button[@id="ext-gen756"][@class=" x-btn-text"]');
```

You can also try the same using `AND` -

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//button[@id="ext-gen756" and @class=" x-btn-text"]');
```

**EDITED**

Your `xpath` seem incorrect. Use following -

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//div[@class="x-combo-list-item"][contains(.,"Global ID")]');
```

Comment: there is a white space at the begin of class, add it and the answer will be upvoted

Comment: @Narendra I have edited Question, please have a look on other section

Comment: @NarendraRajput above mentioned xpath is also not working :(

Comment: I'm not much aware with `python` . Make sure your element is not under `IFrame` if it is then first need to switch frame. If not  then use some `Explicitwait` Refer this -http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html

Answer (score 0):

Just answering my own question after a long time had a look on this. The Question was posted when I was new in xpath topics.

```
<button type="button" id="ext-gen756" class=" x-btn-text">Save</button>
```

in terms of id and class:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@id='ext-gen756'][@class=' x-btn-text']")
```

Also sometime if Id's are dynamic and changes for every reload of the page then you may try:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[@type='Save'][contains(@id,'ext-gen')][@class=' x-btn-text']")
```

Here I have used @type and for the @id contains option as prefix(ext-gen) usually remains the same for the dynamic ID's